# Pipe type message detection

Tags: c, unix, pipe, fork

In some C code, I have a parent process that reads a message from a child process through a PIPE channel. 
The child process will send an integer value between 0 and 9 or a string (char *) message.
In the parent process, how can I test if the child process has sent either the integer value or the string (char *) message?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipes work with unstructured binary data (just like all other files), so the only way to tell is to pass more data, like a flag indicating what will be sent next. If you're working on a large project, you can simplify your life by using a serialization system like Google's Protocol Buffers.

Of course, in your particular case you can rely on the first byte of the message being zero iff the message is integer, but it's a homework-grade solution :)

Comment: Whether he could rely on the first byte being zero to distinguish numbers from strings depends on the endianness of the system, and on whether empty strings must be supported.  The idea to wrap the communication in some kind of protocol is much better, whether it's a canned protocol or a home-grown one.